# How do I join all in one sql table and with first occurence from another table, keeping all from first table

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

Following SQLite (android Room) query:

(UPDATE 2021.01.03 07:43 GMT: I have enhanced the Q)

```
select  o.*, gi.* 
from orders as o
left join galleryitems as gi on gi.siteId = o.siteId 
order by orderId asc
```

with theese given tables:

```
orders: unique key is orderid

o.orderId | siteId      | col1      | col2
----------+-------------+-----------+----------
456       | 1001        | o.456c1r1 | o.456c2r1 
457       | 1002        | o.457c1r1 | o.457c2r1
458       | 1003        | o.458c1r1 | o.458c2r1
459       | 1004        | o.459c1r1 | o.459c2r1
460       | 1005        | o.460c1r1 | o.460c2r1
461       | 1006        | o.461c1r1 | o.461c2r1
462       | 1007        | o.462c1r1 | o.462c2r1
```

```
galleryitems: unique key is galleryId, reference to ordertable is gi.siteId

gi.galleryID | gi.col1     | gi.col2     | gi.siteId 
-------------+-------------+-------------+----------
0001         | gi1001.c1r1 | gi1001.c2r1 | 1001      
0002         | gi1001.c1r2 | gi1001.c2r2 | 1001      
0003         | gi1002.c1r1 | gi1002.c1r1 | 1002
0004         | gi1003.c1r1 | gi1003.c1r1 | 1005
0005         | gi1003.c1r2 | gi1003.c1r2 | 1005
```

gives this result:

```
o.orderId | o.siteId | col1      | col2      | gi.galleryID | gi.col1     | gi.col2     | gi.siteId 
----------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+----------
456       | 1001     | o.456c1r1 | o.456c2r1 | 0001         | gi1001.c1r1 | gi1001.c2r1 | 1001   <-- "duplicates"   
456       | 1001     | o.456c1r1 | o.456c2r1 | 0002         | gi1001.c1r2 | gi1001.c2r2 | 1001   <-- "duplicates"
457       | 1002     | o.457c1r1 | o.457c2r1 | 0003         | gi1002.c1r1 | gi1002.c1r1 | 1002
458       | 1003     | o.458c1r1 | o.458c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
459       | 1004     | o.459c1r1 | o.459c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
460       | 1005     | o.460c1r1 | o.460c2r1 | 0004         | gi1003.c1r1 | gi1003.c1r1 | 1005   <-- "duplicates"
460       | 1005     | o.460c1r1 | o.460c2r1 | 0005         | gi1003.c1r2 | gi1003.c1r2 | 1005   <-- "duplicates"
461       | 1006     | o.461c1r1 | o.461c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
462       | 1007     | o.462c1r1 | o.462c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
```

as you see below, I want data present from `gi` only when they are present, but only the first occurence, so they don't get "duplicated" (just fill inn data if gi.siteid is found (first occurence is ok, or even counted, if it is possible during joining), otherwise `gi` fields should be `<null>` ):

```
o.orderId | o.siteId | col1      | col2      | gi.galleryID | gi.col1     | gi.col2     | gi.siteId 
----------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+----------
456       | 1001     | o.456c1r1 | o.456c2r1 | 0001         | gi1001.c1r1 | gi1001.c2r1 | 1001   <-- no "duplicates"   
457       | 1002     | o.457c1r1 | o.457c2r1 | 0003         | gi1002.c1r1 | gi1002.c1r1 | 1002
458       | 1003     | o.458c1r1 | o.458c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
459       | 1004     | o.459c1r1 | o.459c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
460       | 1005     | o.460c1r1 | o.460c2r1 | 0004         | gi1003.c1r1 | gi1003.c1r1 | 1005   <-- no "duplicates"
461       | 1006     | o.461c1r1 | o.461c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
462       | 1007     | o.462c1r1 | o.462c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
```

I see there are many suggestions, but they don't cope with SQLite limited library.

Any suggestions ?

Using androidx room.

Comment: *...only the first occurence...* according to which column? Is it the min value of the column `gi.row1`?

Comment: Sorry, I see there's an ertor in my Q, I'll correct it tomorrow...

Comment: I have updated my Q, to make a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with aggregation to get the row with the min value of `galleryitems.row1` only, by using a feature of SQLite that is not standard SQL but it is [documented](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing):

```
select  min(gi.row1) as row1, gi.row2, gi.siteId, o.* 
from orders as o left join galleryitems as gi 
on gi.siteId = o.siteId 
group by o.siteId
order by orderId asc
```

Or use `galleryitems`'s `rowid` to define that *first occurence*:

```
select  gi.*, o.* 
from orders as o left join galleryitems as gi 
on gi.siteId = o.siteId 
group by o.siteId
having min(gi.rowid) or min(gi.rowid) is null
order by orderId asc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=17566ef9655bd05c127eb08440ea161f).

Comment: Thanx for swift answer, I have enhanced my Q a little bit, your suggestion works quite well, and I have even tested it with a counter instead of min (actually `count(gi.siteId)') and could then collect the count of the occurences. Even better... thank you very much.

Comment: @RoarGrønmo fine if it works for you. But you should know that by using COUNT() instead of MIN(), although the result of COUNT() is correct, the row that you get for each siteid is unpredictable. With MIN() you get the row that contains the min row1, but with COUNT() there is no guarantee that you get that row.

Answer (score 0):

@forpas corrected me to broad path, and I could even enhance it. Thanx for that !

```
select count(gi.siteId) as cc, gi.*, o.*
from orders as o
left join galleryitems as gi on gi.siteId = o.siteId
group by o.siteId
```

This results now into this result: (note !! group by o.siteId not gi.siteId)

```
cc |o.orderId | o.siteId | col1      | col2      | gi.galleryID | gi.col1     | gi.col2     | gi.siteId 
---+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+----------
2  |456       | 1001     | o.456c1r1 | o.456c2r1 | 0001         | gi1001.c1r1 | gi1001.c2r1 | 1001   <-- no "duplicates"   
1  |457       | 1002     | o.457c1r1 | o.457c2r1 | 0003         | gi1002.c1r1 | gi1002.c1r1 | 1002
0  |458       | 1003     | o.458c1r1 | o.458c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
0  |459       | 1004     | o.459c1r1 | o.459c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
2  |460       | 1005     | o.460c1r1 | o.460c2r1 | 0004         | gi1003.c1r1 | gi1003.c1r1 | 1005   <-- no "duplicates"
0  |461       | 1006     | o.461c1r1 | o.461c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
0  |462       | 1007     | o.462c1r1 | o.462c2r1 | <null>       | <null>      | <null>      | <null>
```